# Airplane mode after rebooot

Tags: reboot, airplane-mode

After a reboot, my computer defaults to "Airplane mode".  I have Ubuntu 12.04 and was wondering if others were experiencing this and if there was a fix.  I have a HP G60.

Answer (score 1):

The same problem happened with me.

I think the only solution is to disable airplane mode manually.  I have tried looking on the internet but there is nothing else I can find on the matter.